# Facebook like button posts not displaying

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I got the code from Facebook and got the like button and feed of posts working perfectly on my website.  However, about 2 weeks ago the posts disappeared...  The like button is still displaying correctly on my site, but the posts are gone.  Nothing changed in the code on my site, i even tried getting the code from facebook and doing it all over again, but nothing changed.

Is there a setting on the Facebook business page that changed?  or is there something else i should try?

Here is the code i'm trying to use:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=348803085283236&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ontheballpetcare" data-width="270" 
data-height="800" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="true" data-
stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Comment: UPDATE:  I just signed out of facebook and went to the website.  And it works fine.  So why does it not display when my browser is logged in to facebook?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the likebox currently. If you are not logged in to facebook you will not see posts and you will see an extra like. 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/580638328728973/

Comment: On another note. Lol @ the off by 1 bug. Excellent programmers over at Facebook.